# Firebase Rest API - Call signatures

Tags: rest, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to access the firebase cloud function using Rest API.

Here is the test function:

```
exports.test =  functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
  console.log('came here');
  res.status(200).json({"message":"it worked"});
})
```

I test using:
`curl 'https://<project_id>.firebaseio.com/test.json?auth=<auth_key>`

I expect the response to be 
`{"message": "it worked"}`

But what I get back is:

```
{
  "-LY...." : true,
  "-LY..": true
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Also is my endpoint like above or should  it 
the cloudfunctions endpoint 
`(https://us-central1-<project-id.cloudfunctions.net/)`
as in this video
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qZ1EFnFOGvE

Sadly cloudfunctions endpoint also did not work for me.

Comment: I'm confused what you're trying to accomplish here. It looks like you're mixing up the Realtime Database REST API with a Cloud Function HTTP trigger.  They're not related.

Comment: Your current call is reading from the Firebase Realtime Database, and is getting the result that is expected from there. If you want to instead call your Cloud Function you will need to call its endpoint, which is shown after you deploy the function. If that doesn't work, update your question with the call you do to the Cloud Function URL and the result you get.

Comment: Thanks Frank van Puffelen.

Comment: My cloud endpoint is as follows:
https://<project_id>.cloudfunctions.net/test.json?auth=<auth_key>
The error that I get is Could not get any response
There was an error connecting to https://<project_id>.cloudfunctions.net/test.json?auth=<auth_key>.
Why this might have happened:
The server couldn't send a response:
Fix this by turning off 'SSL certificate verification' in Settings > General
Proxy configured incorrectly
Ensure that proxy is configured correctly in Settings > Proxy
Request timeout:
Change request timeout in Settings > General
My request timeout is 0=infinity

Answer (score 0):

your link `https://<project_id>.firebaseio.com/test.json?auth=<auth_key>`

is a link of `realtime database` REST API.

If you are looking **`the url of your cloud functions`**, you will get it when you deploy your cloud functions for the first time. Did you already deploy your cloud functions?

It will be something like this : `https://us-central1-<project_id>.cloudfunctions.net/test`

You can also find the cloud function url in `console.firebase` in `functions` section